# Custom rails routing helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am having issues getting my helper method names to work properly, any suggestions would be great:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :junkie, only: [:show, :index, :destroy], as: :junkie do
  get :merge, on: :collection
end
```

So I was having issues because I the singular form of `junkies` is `junky`, but when I make this change and look at the routes it changes the `#merge` helper to:

```
merge_junkie_index GET    /junkies/merge(.:format)              junkies#merge
```

Is there any way to change this to just `merge_junkie`? I tried removing it from the resource black and using the match syntax: `get "junkies/merge" => "junkies#merge", as: :junkie` but for some odd reason this directed me to the `show` method even though the route was right.

Comment: This is so weird, I can get the route to look correct when I run rake routes, BUT when I enter that route in the browser it hits the show action. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DigitalCake  `merge_junkies GET    /junkies/merge(.:format)              junkies#merge`

Comment: it would help to see all of them to see if there is a conflict. Sometimes the order of routes can cause this type of problem, though I'm really reaching since I dont see a problem off hand.

Comment: @DigitalCake 
`junkie GET    /junkies/:id(.:format)                junkies#show`
`DELETE /junkies/:id(.:format)                junkies#destroy`
`merge_junkies GET    /junkies/merge(.:format)        junkies#merge`
`save_merge_junkies POST   /junkies/save_merge(.:format)         junkies#save_merge`
`junkies GET    /junkies(.:format)                    junkies#index`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is a ugly one but it works, since the show route is the only one that is affected by the `as: :junkie` you can break it out put the `merge` route in a separate block. The ordering of the resource also matters for some reason, if you do not put the merge first, it will interpret the url `/junkie/merge/` as a id and hit the `show` action. So it should look like this in your routes file:

```
resources :junkies, only: [:index] do
  get :merge, on: :collection
end
resources :junkies, only: [:show, :destroy], as: :junkie
```